# Git error, Unable to acces, error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: git, ssl

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Reminder>git push
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/Project.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

I'm struggling with following error. I have tried plenty of solutions from other similar topics but none helped. The error occurs also when im trying to clone other repository. From what I found out, this is problem with wrong path to certificate. The certificate path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt. For some reason it the error shows that is using other path.

I already tried this:

1. reinstall git
2. install older version of git
3. `git config --system http.sslcainfo 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt'`
4. `git config --system http.sslverify false`
5. manually copied folder into path which has been showed in error, git freeze and nothing happens

After using this command:`git config --list`
I get this:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslverify=false
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
credential.helper=manager
user.name=beorn
user.email=xxxx@email.com
http.sslverify=false
```

Even though it print good path, git using wrong...
Any ideas what can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't find solution to connect by using certificate but I manage to do workaround.
Now im using SSH key and I have no problem with pushing. [https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair][1]

Comment: Your answer could be a comment really